# db2look from SQL

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Is it possible to get the table structure like `db2look` from SQL?

Or the only way is from command line? Thus, by wrapping a external stored procedure in C I could call the db2look, but that is not what I am looking for.

Clarification added later:

I want to know which tables have the non logged option from SQL.

Comment: Is it table structure you want or field meta data?  Usually it is field meta data which is easily found in `SYSCAT.COLUMNS`

Comment: I want to know which tables have the non logged option from SQL.

Comment: I'm guessing it is SYSCAT.TABLES.LOGGED.  This is not rocket science; a simple google search reveals extensive documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001063.html

Comment: @AngocA You're looking for the `LOG_ATTRIBUTE` column in `SYSCAT.TABLES`, but you'll find that it's not useful anymore – DB2 stopped requiring tables to be *created* with `NOT LOGGED INITIALLY` in order to be able to use `ALTER TABLE ... ACTIVATE NOT LOGGED INITIALLY` back in DB2 9.1.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create the table structure from regular SQL and the public DB2 catalog - however, it is complex and requires some deeper skills.

The metadata is available in the [DB2 catalog views in the `SYSCAT` schema](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011297.html). For a regular table you would first start off by looking into the values in `SYSCAT.TABLES` and `SYSCAT.COLUMNS`. From there you would need to branch off to other views depending on what table and column options you are after, whether time-travel tables, special partitioning rules, or many other options are involved.

Answer (score 1):

Serge Rielau published an article on developerWorks called [Backup and restore SQL schemas for DB2 Universal Database](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0602rielau/index.html) that provides a set of stored procedures that will do exactly what you're looking for.

The article is quite old (2006) so you may need to put some time in to update the procedures to be able to handle features that were added to DB2 since the date of publication, but the procedures may work for you now and are a nice jumping off point.